# UnityPlayerActivity:java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Error appears when I call UnityPlayerActivity from Unity.
Please help.

AndroidJavaException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can not create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare ()

java code

```
public class sampleActivity extends UnityPlayerActivity {

   private mActivity;
   private mAppId;
   private mLicenseKey;
   private mService;

   public sampleActivity (Activity activity, String appId, String licenseKey, String service){
     mActivity    = activity;
     mAppId       = appId;
     mLicenseKey  = licenseKey;
     mService     = service;
   }
}
```

cs code

```
AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
AndroidJavaObject activity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
Plugin = new AndroidJavaObject("com.sample.sampleActivity ",new object[]{activity,appId,licenceKey,sku});
```

Comment: That error generally means that you are modifying or accessing UI thread from worker thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been resolved

[[Closed] JNI Exception using Android Plugin](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/437708/jni-exception-using-android-plugin.html?sort=oldest)